# R lm() nested formulas give different results

Tags: r, lm, contrasts, nested-data

Online sources show two supposedly equivalent ways to write an R linear model formula with nested factors:

```
y ~ a/b       # b is nested within a
y ~ b %in% a  # b is nested within a
```

Yet when you run data through lm() with these two formulas, you get very different results, as if the default contrasts are different.  Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there may be a problem in some of the documentation, or at least an opportunity to make things clearer.

In the document ["An Introduction to R"](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf), the first place that we see the `%in%` term for a formula it implies that your 2 formulas give an identical result: "the second two specify the same nested classification".

But if you scroll/search down further then it says that `M_1 / M_2` equates to `M_1 + M_2 %in% M_1` which differs by a main effect term, not having the main effect term would change the interpretation and even how contrasts are applied.

The second version is what I remember having learned about the `a/b` notation, but given the description where we first see these terms it is easy to see why you (and probably many others) would expect identical results.

Comment: Thanks, that is it.  There are at least two other sources online but I might have trouble finding them again.

Answer (score 4):

Which sources? They are wrong. `a/b` is equivalent to `a + a:b` and `a + b %in% a`.

Comment: One of the likely sources seems to be "An Introduction to R".  Technically it just says that they both specify the same nested model and does not guarantee identical results, but the way it is written (the first place `%in%` is mentioned) does not rule out that interpretation.